# -0 not equals 0

Tags: php, floating-point

I have a function that calculates a value, which is a float:

```
function crunch (float $a, float $b):float
{
  //do stuff
  return $result;
}

function testSomething (float $a, float $b):bool
{
  //if $result is -0 that returns false
  $result = crunch($a, $b);
  return $result === 0;
}
```

Why is **-0 not equal to 0** and how can if safely check if that number is zero, assuming that `0` should be the same as `-0`?

**UPDATE**

Since there was the question for more details. I have a class `Vec2` which has `x()` and `y()` getters, and a method called `cross`, which looks like that:

```
public function cross(Vec2 $vec2):float
{
  return ($this->_x * $vec2->_y) - ($vec2->_x * $this->_y);
}
```

Running this code:

```
$cross = $this->cross($d);
```

results in that debugger output

[image]

and `$cross === 0` evaluates to `false`;

Comment: As a side note.. shouldn't be `float $a, float $b` instead of `float $a, $float $b`

Comment: sure! it's updated…

Comment: Can you get into a bit more detail how the results are generated or really look like? `-0` isn't a thing and this is true: `var_dump(-0 === 0);`

Comment: ^^^^^ So, `echo serialize($result);` not `-0`

Comment: I can read those results from the debugger, xdebug, ide phpstorm…

Comment: Please get the type and exact value of `$result` I am sure it's either some super small float value !== 0 or a string maybe?

Comment: What about `return $result === 0.;`?

Comment: Yeah, was about to say, 0 is int not float :D You need to (float)0 compare.

Comment: Your problem relates to floats, not to `0` and `-0`

Comment: Does that mean that a float zero and an int zero a different, even if they represent the same quantity: nothing?

Comment: Very much so @phillipp, infact there has always been an issue with floats not always being accurate.

Comment: I ♥ PHP! I will ever do!

Comment: Technically the downvoted answer is right in that you can avoid that by using a type insensitive comparison like `$result == 0` BUT that's a bit ugly, given that you know the datatype of `$result` so IMHO making sure the 0 is actually float is preferable.

Comment: @philipp I added the `floating-point` tag for this, seems relevant. If you disagree, let me know and I'll remove it. Or, you can if you want also; either way ;-)

Comment: you're welcome @philipp *cheers*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cast the 0 to float. It's probably failing because 0 as literal is an int, and the result is a float, so === is false because of types.

At least doing something like this, fails like your case (the result is false):

```
php -r '$a = (float) -0; $b = 0; echo ($a === $b);'
```

The result is true in this case:

```
php -r '$a = (float) -0; $b = (float) 0; echo ($a == $b);'
```

Comment: Instead of type juggling, I prefer the shorter syntax. `0.`

Comment: `$floatvalue === 0.` evaluates to true! All the attention to the `.` at the and end`.`

Comment: that's right. I prefer 0.0  or 0.00, it's more natural reading in my opinion

Comment: Ofcourse, `.0` would also. Its just a defined float. Careful with string concatenation of floats.

Answer (score 4):

1. Negative zero isn't a thing. But a negative value smaller than the configured precision for floating point display is.
2. You can't reliably check direct equivalence between two floats, you can only reasonably check that the difference between two floats is smaller than you care about for a given calculation.

eg:

```
function float_equiv(float $a, float $b, float $epsilon=NULL) {
    // default to PHP's configured display precision
    $epsilon = $epsilon ?: pow(10, -1*ini_get('precision'));

    if( abs($a - $b) < $epsilon ) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: `precsion` is a possible typo, should be `precision`, *n'est-ce pas true?*

Comment: Third time is the charm.

Comment: ^ that it is ;-)

Comment: NIce Test, but that one is related to type conversions and `0.` is something completely different than just `0`, at least in PHP logic.

Answer (score 0):

Just to illustrate the accepted answer by @monstercode

Math logic and computer logic are separated entities.
We intuitively know that -0 = 0 but in computer terms the sign of a number is stored separately from the number (like a meta data) - this is what floats do.

In that case an integer is compared to a float.

```
$result_1 = 1234*0;// remains an integer
$result_2 = -1234*0;// remains an integer

$result_3 = -1.234*0;// becomes a float
$result_4 = 1.234*0; // becomes a float

var_dump($result_1 === 0); // true
var_dump($result_2 === 0); // true

var_dump($result_3 === 0); // false
var_dump($result_4 === 0); // false
```